# How do I restric access with nginx location to url matching an expression with a string and a number?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have the following path as a Nginx Location :

/api/users

The url that my users access is /api/users?id=109238717283223

The problem is I don't want the direct path /api/users to be accessible, and the goal is to allow access only when the url contains users?id=number(with exact amount of digits)

How could I achieve this with a regex ?

Comment: Can you please add few more concrete examples for what is allowed and what is not? It is not pretty clear from the above description.

Answer (score 0):

Individual arguments can be accessed using the `$arg_` variable prefix. It can be tested against a regular expression using an `if` directive. For example, an exact match location that ensures that the `id` parameter is exactly 15 digits:

```
location = /api/users {
    if ($arg_id ~ ^\d{15}$) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

Read [this documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) regarding limitations using the `if` directive.